# Performing git pull operation from a django view

Tags: python, django, git, subprocess

I am trying to perform a git pull operation when a django view is called inside the view.

```py
cmd = 'cd %s && git pull origin master' % dir_path
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

I get below error in stderr:

```
fatal: unsafe repository ('/home/user/my_dir' is owned by someone else) To add an exception for this directory, call: git config --global --add safe.directory /home/user/my_dir
```

I believe it is ownership related issue but not sure about the solution. Command runs just fine when I run it from shell.
It is currently running from django runserver.

I have tried adding this directory to safe.directories

```
git config --global --add safe.directory /home/user/my_dir
```

but still see the same error

Comment: You'll need to configure *django's* `--global` Git configuration so that *django's* Git commands believe that this directory is safe for *django* to use. You've told your Git software that it's safe for *you* to use.